# What's file serial number?

Tags: c, gnu

I found a struct member(name is d_fileno) of 'struct dirent' from [Gnu C library [dirent.h]](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html)
. 
I read documentation but I didn't understand the meaning of file serial number. I couldn't find any satisfactory answer on Google. 
So, I decided wrote a program to see what looks like the file serial numbers.

**Output**

```
$./fileno ..
file_serial_number   file_name
[6838726]        [source]
[6562883]        [..]
[6838661]        [lstfl]
[6838718]        [.]
[6826161]        [research]
[6838720]        [starcase]
```

So, what's the meaning of these numbers?

**Related part from program**:

```
...
while((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
    {
      printf("[%li]\t\t [%s]\n",pDirent->d_fileno, pDirent->d_name);
    }

  closedir(pDir);
...
```

Comment: The term FSN is intended to be a neutral term that corresponds to some concept in every file system, even in file systems that do not have the concept of inodes per se.  In terms of `struct stat`, it corresponds to `st_ino` (as the page you link to says); the combination of `st_ino` and `st_dev` should uniquely identify the file.  Note that `d_fileno` is not standard per POSIX; only the `d_name` element of `struct dirent` is mandated by POSIX (also as noted in the page you link to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> The file serial number, which distinguishes this file from all other files on the same device.

You can understand it in terms of `inode` number. Using the inode number, we can refer to `inode data structure` of the file which contains metadata about the file such as

- Size of file
- Device ID
- User ID of the file
- Group ID of the file
- The file mode information and access privileges for owner, group and others
- File protection flags
- The timestamps for file creation, modification etc

[inodes](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/01/linux-inodes/)

Comment: so its a address from all other files?

Comment: No, you can use this number to refer to the file metadata information.

Comment: @H.Emre: it is a unique number that identifies the file contents.  Multiple names can refer to the same FSN (inode).

Comment: How do you get i-node (struct stat) from i-number that a member of struct dirent?  My 'Unix Systems Programming' book showed example by lstat(filepath, &st), look for the whole book did not find i-number => i-node. That should be straight forward.